# How to adjust column labels in heatmap.3

Tags: r, heatmap

The following is my code for heatmap.3:

```
heatmap.3(x = as.matrix(res), dist.FUN = dist2, scale = 'row', color.FUN = col_ylgnbu, 
                           cex.main = 2, trace = 'none', srtCol = 45, adjCol = c(1,0.1),
                           main = paste(title), 
                           key = T, cexRow = 2, cexCol = 1)
```

I get the following heatmap using this code:

[image]

My question is how can I adjust the column labels so that they don't overlap the heatmap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could set **adjCol** to center justify and **offsetCol** to move the labels down:

```
heatmap.3(x = as.matrix(res), dist.FUN = dist2, scale = 'row', 
    color.FUN = col_ylgnbu, 
    cex.main = 2, trace = 'none', srtCol = 45, 
    adjCol = c(1,0), offsetCol=1
    main = paste(title), 
    key = T, cexRow = 2, cexCol = 1)
```

More notes here: http://earlglynn.github.io/RNotes/package/gplots/heatmap2.html

Comment: It is giving me the following errors: `In plot.window(...) : "adjCol" is not a graphical parameter
In plot.window(...) : "offsetCol" is not a graphical parameter`

Comment: Looking at the script, adjCol should only work if srtCol is NULL, did you see this error before?

Comment: Yes, I saw this error before too. I do want the column names to be rotated at 45 degrees and vertically adjusted. So I figured I would use both adjCol and srtCol. However, it seems like heatmap.3 doesn't really inherit all the arguments of heatmap.2, as is commonly known.

Comment: Yeah, looks like an issue when the text is added, there's no option for changing the text position.    

text(1:nc,.sideCol,labels=labCol,srt=srtCol,pos=1,xpd=TRUE,cex=cexCol)